# Unification with sequence variables and flexible arity functions

Tags: algorithm, haskell, generics

Today I wrote an implementation of the unification algorithm found in [Temur Kutsia's 2002 paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2553137_Unification_with_Sequence_Variables_And_Flexible_Arity_Symbols_and_its_Extension_with_Pattern-Terms). I didn't just do this for fun, it's related to other research I'm doing. I'm feeling more confident in my Haskell these days, and I was going to go through this code to clean it up myself but, since this is a pretty general and nicely self-contained module, I thought I'd ask for some outside review to see what others would do. I am open to all suggestions, particularly related to the massive transformations function.

Other questions I had: does it look like I can make use of `Foldable`/`Traversable`? Does it look worth it to add a `Substitutable` type class? Am I doing lots of unnecessary work (probably)?

*Note: I changed all variables ending with apostrophes to end with p since it was breaking the syntax highlighter. Sorry if that's ugly.

```
module Unification where

import Control.Monad.State

import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Debug.Trace

-- a is the set from which both individual and sequence variables are taken
-- c is the set of constant values
data Term a c
    = Const c
    | IVar a
    | SVar a
    | Fun a [Term a c]
    | Seq [Term a c]
    deriving Eq

instance (Show a, Show c) => Show (Term a c) where
    show (Const c) = show c
    show (IVar a) = show a
    show (SVar a) = show a
    show (Fun a ts) = show a ++ "(" ++ (concat $ intersperse "," $ map show ts) ++ ")"
    show (Seq ts) = "[" ++ (concat $ intersperse "," $ map show ts) ++ "]"

type Equation a c = (Term a c, Term a c)

data UniTree a c = Success
                | Failure
                | Problem (Equation a c) [(Substitution a c, UniTree a c)]
                deriving (Eq, Show)

type Substitution a c = Map.Map a (Term a c)

vars :: Ord a => Term a c -> Set.Set a
vars (Fun v ts) = Set.insert v $ Set.unions (map vars ts)
vars (SVar v) = Set.singleton v
vars (IVar v) = Set.singleton v
vars _ = Set.empty

seqVars :: Ord a => Term a c -> Set.Set a
seqVars (Fun v ts) = Set.unions (map seqVars ts)
seqVars (SVar v) = Set.singleton v
seqVars _ = Set.empty

powerset :: Ord a => Set.Set a -> [Set.Set a]
powerset = map Set.fromAscList . filterM (const [False,True]) . Set.toList

substitute :: Ord a => Substitution a c -> Term a c -> Term a c
substitute env (IVar v) =
    Map.findWithDefault (IVar v) v env
substitute env (SVar v) =
    Map.findWithDefault (SVar v) v env
substitute env (Fun v ts) =
    Fun v $ flattenSeq (map (substitute env) ts)
substitute env (Seq ts) =
    Seq $ flattenSeq (map (substitute env) ts)
substitute env t = t

substituteSeq :: Ord a => Substitution a c -> [Term a c] -> [Term a c]
substituteSeq env ts = flattenSeq $ map (substitute env) ts

flattenSeq :: [Term a c] -> [Term a c]
flattenSeq [] = []
flattenSeq (Seq subs:ts) = subs ++ ts
flattenSeq (t:ts) = t:flattenSeq ts

composeUnifySubs :: Ord a => Substitution a c -> Substitution a c -> Substitution a c
composeUnifySubs e1 e2 =
    let e1p = Map.filterWithKey cleanSubs $ Map.map (substitute e2) e1
    -- Relies on left-biased implementation of Map.union to remove overlapped elements from e2
    in e1p `Map.union` e2
    where cleanSubs v1 (IVar v2) = not $ v1 == v2
        cleanSubs v1 (Seq [SVar v2]) = not $ v1 == v2
        cleanSubs _ _ = True

unifyTree :: (Show a, Ord a, Show c, Eq c) => State [a] a -> Term a c -> Term a c -> UniTree a c
unifyTree getFresh t1 t2 =
    Problem (t1p,t2p) [(env, transformed env) | (env,_) <- ts]
    where (Problem (t1p,t2p) ts) = projections t1 t2
        transformed env =
            evalState (transformations getFresh (substitute env t1p) (substitute env t2p))
                        (Set.toList $ vars t1 `Set.union` vars t2)

-- only used for the first level of the tree
projections :: (Ord a, Eq c) => Term a c -> Term a c -> UniTree a c
projections t1 t2 =
    Problem (t1,t2) [(env, Success) | env <- emptyEnvs]
    where svars = seqVars t1 `Set.union` seqVars t2
        emptyEnvs = map toEmpties $ powerset svars
        toEmpties = Map.fromSet (const (Seq [])) 

-- used for all levels after the first level of the tree
transformations :: (Show a, Ord a, Show c, Eq c) => State [a] a -> Term a c -> Term a c -> State [a] (UniTree a c)
transformations _ t1@(IVar _) t2@(IVar _)
    | t1 == t2 = return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(Map.empty, Success)]
transformations _ t1@(Const _) t2@(Const _)
    | t1 == t2 = return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(Map.empty, Success)]
    | otherwise = return Failure
transformations _ t1@(Fun _ _) t2@(Fun _ _)
    | t1 == t2 = return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(Map.empty, Success)]
transformations _ (Fun _ _) (Const _) = return Failure
transformations _ (Const _) (Fun _ _) = return Failure
transformations _ t1@(IVar v) t2
    | v `Set.member` vars t2 = return Failure
    | otherwise = return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(Map.singleton v t2, Success)]
transformations _ t1 t2@(IVar v)
    | v `Set.member` vars t1 = return Failure
    | otherwise = return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(Map.singleton v t1, Success)]
transformations _ (Fun v1 _) (Fun v2 _)
    | v1 /= v2 = return Failure
transformations _ (Fun _ []) (Fun _ (t:ts)) = return Failure
transformations _ (Fun _ (t:ts)) (Fun _ []) = return Failure
transformations _ (Fun _ (t1@(SVar v):t1s)) (Fun _ (t2:t2s))
    | t1 /= t2 && v `Set.member` seqVars t2 = return Failure
transformations _ (Fun _ (t1:t1s)) (Fun _ (t2@(SVar v):t2s))
    | t1 /= t2 && v `Set.member` seqVars t1 = return Failure
transformations getFresh (Fun f (t1@(SVar v1):t1s)) (Fun _ (t2@(SVar v2):t2s))
    | v1 == v2 = do
        transformed <- transformations getFresh (Fun f t1s) (Fun f t2s)
        return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(Map.empty, transformed)]
    | otherwise = do
        v1p <- getFresh
        v2p <- getFresh
        let sub1 = Map.singleton v1 (Seq [t2])
            sub2 = Map.singleton v1 (Seq [t2, (SVar v1p)])
            sub3 = Map.singleton v2 (Seq [t1, (SVar v2p)])
        trans1 <- transformations getFresh (Fun f (substituteSeq sub1 t1s)) (Fun f (substituteSeq sub1 t2s))
        trans2 <- transformations getFresh (Fun f (SVar v1p:(substituteSeq sub2 t1s))) (Fun f (substituteSeq sub2 t2s))
        trans3 <- transformations getFresh (Fun f (substituteSeq sub3 t1s)) (Fun f (SVar v2p:(substituteSeq sub3 t2s)))
        return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(sub1, trans1),(sub2, trans2),(sub3, trans3)]
transformations getFresh (Fun f (t1@(SVar v):t1s)) (Fun _ (t2:t2s))
    | not $ v `Set.member` vars t2 = do
        vp <- getFresh
        let sub1 = Map.singleton v (Seq [t2])
            sub2 = Map.singleton v (Seq [t2,(SVar vp)])
        trans1 <- transformations getFresh (Fun f (substituteSeq sub1 t1s)) (Fun f (substituteSeq sub1 t2s))
        trans2 <- transformations getFresh (Fun f (SVar vp:(substituteSeq sub2 t1s))) (Fun f (substituteSeq sub2 t2s))
        return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(sub1, trans1),(sub2, trans2)]
transformations getFresh (Fun f (t1:t1s)) (Fun _ (t2@(SVar v):t2s))
    | not $ v `Set.member` vars t1 = do
        vp <- getFresh
        let sub1 = Map.singleton v (Seq [t1])
            sub2 = Map.singleton v (Seq [t1,(SVar vp)])
        trans1 <- transformations getFresh (Fun f (substituteSeq sub1 t1s)) (Fun f (substituteSeq sub1 t2s))
        trans2 <- transformations getFresh (Fun f (substituteSeq sub2 t1s)) (Fun f (SVar vp:(substituteSeq sub2 t2s)))
        return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(sub1, trans1), (sub2, trans2)]
transformations getFresh (Fun f (t1:t1s)) (Fun _ (t2:t2s)) = do
    transformed <- transformations getFresh t1 t2
    case transformed of
        Failure -> return Failure
        Problem _ [(sub, Success)] -> do
            transformed <- transformations getFresh (Fun f (substituteSeq sub t1s)) (Fun f (substituteSeq sub t2s))
            return $ Problem (t1,t2) [(sub, transformed)]
        Problem _ rs -> do
            alltransformed <- mapM doSub rs
            return $ Problem (t1,t2) alltransformed
    where doSub (sub, Problem (q,r) _) = do
            let t1sp = substituteSeq sub t1s
                t2sp = substituteSeq sub t2s
            transformed <- transformations getFresh (Fun f (q:t1sp)) (Fun f (r:t2sp))
            return (sub, transformed)
        doSub (sub, Failure) = return (sub, Failure)
        doSub (sub, Success) = return (sub, Success)
transformations _ t1 t2 = error $ "got: " ++ show t1 ++ " " ++ show t2

unifyMapsFromTree :: Ord a => UniTree a c -> [Substitution a c]
unifyMapsFromTree = catMaybes . unifyMaybeMaps Map.empty

unifyMaybeMaps :: Ord a => Substitution a c -> UniTree a c -> [Maybe (Substitution a c)]
unifyMaybeMaps _ Failure = [Nothing]
unifyMaybeMaps env Success = [Just env]
unifyMaybeMaps env (Problem _ ts) = concat $ map (unifyMaybeMap env) ts

unifyMaybeMap :: Ord a => Substitution a c -> (Substitution a c, UniTree a c) -> [Maybe (Substitution a c)]
unifyMaybeMap env (_, Failure) = [Nothing]
unifyMaybeMap env (envp, Success) = [Just $ composeUnifySubs env envp]
unifyMaybeMap env (envp, Problem _ ts) =
    concat $ map (unifyMaybeMap (composeUnifySubs env envp)) ts

unifiers :: (Show a, Ord a, Show c, Eq c) => State [a] a -> Term a c -> Term a c -> [Substitution a c]
unifiers getFresh t1 t2 =
    let tree = unifyTree getFresh t1 t2
        vs = vars t1 `Set.union` vars t2
    in map (flattenNew vs) $ unifyMapsFromTree tree

flattenNew :: (Show a, Ord a, Show c) => Set.Set a -> Substitution a c -> Substitution a c
flattenNew names sub =
    Map.difference substNew new
    where new = Map.difference sub $ Map.fromSet (const (Seq [])) names
        substNew = Map.map (substitute new) sub
```